# How do I add a static route in Windows?

Tags: windows, routing

When I VPN into my corporate office I can access all of the resources just fine, as if I were in the office, with the exception of one server.  While on the VPN I ping the server by name and get the outside public facing ip address of the server.  They way I use the server, I have to use it by name as opposed to ip address.

How can I add a route in my Windows machine to temporarily resolve this issue?  Lets say the outside address that is returned from the server when I am on the VPN is 48.48.48.48 and the gateway inside the office network is 192.168.1.1 and the inside address of the server I need to connect to is 192.168.1.200.  How would I add the route?  I have tried this route on every interface with no luck:

```
route add 48.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.1.200 IF 1
```

I have a co-worker who is on vacation that did make a static route in the Windows routing table work when he was having the same issue so I know it's possible.  Suggestions?

Comment: I suggest letting your network admins know that this is broken, so they can fix it properly. You should not have to create static routes yourself.

Comment: I do agree.  The person responsible for the network is out for a couple days.  So, id like to know for two reasons.  First, I plan on working from home tomorrow and second, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.  My curiosity has me wondering why my static route is not doing what I thought it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the command as administrator, I use my route commands as:

```
route add [HOST] MASK 255.255.255.255 [GATEWAYIP]
route add [NET] MASK [NETMASK] [GATEWAYIP]
```

Could you try to run it as:

`route add 48.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.1.200`

Please, if it doesn't work try to share

`route print` and `ipconfig` output, it is posible that you have a routing overlaping between both interfaces.

Comment: when a route target was covered by current route. possibly umbrella'ed by it, would the route add fail?

Answer (score 1):

Use powershell cmdlets. Get-NetRoute is to look ifIndex and then e. g.:

New-NetRoute -ifIndex 1 -DestinationPrefix 48.0.0.0/24 -NextHop 192.168.1.200